# What does this mean -- C#

Tags: c#

I came across this `while (0 < length --)` and am wondering what the `--` part means? I tried Googling it, however I couldn't find anything in the Operators guide on msdn.
When I remove it to see what error it gives, it says `Memory Limit Exceeded`

[image]

UPDATE: As you can see guys, the - symbol looked like it was put together and I can't tell what it was, that's why I asked this question because I had never seen it before, however it just looks like it was because of the font.

Comment: It's a postfix unary decrement operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx

Comment: [Its 7th in the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6a71f45d.aspx), could you *really* not find anything?

Comment: Hey Sayse, yeah I seen that part, but wasn't too sure if it was it because the first - was a different colour to the second -

Comment: Perhaps the space between `length` and `--` was throwing you off. This space is not mandatory and a bit confusing, but it is simply the unary decrement operator on `length`.

Comment: Thanks Yellow :) indeed it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the decrement operator - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `--` operator decrements (subtracts one from) the variable `length`.